# How to insert a map[string] into a jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a struct `Huygens`:

```
type Huygens struct {
    Worlds map[string]World `json:"worlds" sql:"type:JSONB"`
}

type World struct {
    Diameter int
    Name string
}
```

When I try to insert into a Postgres DB using GORM I get:

```
sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type map[string]huygens.world, a map
```

To insert I simply use `db.Create(&World{})`

Does anyone know how to insert that column as a JSONB column and avoid that error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another way, which makes the model more usable, is to create a type that implements Scan/Value, and in those Unmarshal from/Marshal to JSON:

```golang
type Huygens struct {
    Worlds WorldsMap `json:"worlds"`
}

type World struct {
    Diameter int
    Name string
}

type WorldsMap map[string]World

func (WorldsMap) GormDataType() string {
  return "JSONB"
}

func (w *WorldsMap) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    var bytes []byte
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case []byte:
        bytes = v
    case string:
        bytes = []byte(v)
    default:
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprint("Failed to unmarshal JSONB value:", value))
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, w)
    return err
}

func (w WorldsMap) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(s)
    return string(bytes), err
}
```

Then you can use the `Worlds` field in your code like a map, as opposed to an awkward byte slice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that `Huygens` is a `gorm.Model` and dump your `World` struct to a `[]byte` type.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    
    "gorm.io/datatypes"
)

type Huygens struct {
    gorm.Model
    Worlds datatypes.JSON
}

type World struct {
    Diameter int
    Name string
}

world := World{Diameter: 3, Name: Earth}
b, err := json.Marshal(world)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}

db.Create(&Huygens{Worlds: datatypes.JSON(b)})
```

You can see more [here](https://gorm.io/docs/v2_release_note.html#DataTypes-JSON-as-example).